# How to upload file (selected by user) to Firebase Storage using node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, web, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am working on a project (web, node.js, Firebase functions, hosting and storage) that needs the following functionality:

- user selects file via

```
                    <input type="file" multiple>
```

- other button runs a script that aims to upload selected file(s) to storage.

The problem is that - according to the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) of google storage admin with node.js a file can only be uploaded using a path e.g.:

```
const options = {
  destination: bucket.file('existing-file.png'),
  resumable: false
};

bucket.upload('local-img.png', options, function(err, newFile) {
  // Your bucket now contains:
  // - "existing-file.png" (with the contents of `local-img.png')

});
```

BUT file input field is not allowed to let the browser know what the exact path is.
It allows me to know:

- the file name
- the file URL (URL.createObjectURL(...) -» "blob:https://mis...")
- the file itself as a blob

Summing it up the page cannot hand over the variant the upload mechanism can handle.

Does anybody know the way how to do this?

Google Function call:

```
var imageSelected = document.getElementById("imageSelected");
      var imageList = imageSelected.files;
      var imagePath = imageList.webkitRelativePath;

      for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
        imageFile = imageList[i];
        imageFileURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile).toString();
    
        var imageUpload = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('imageUpload');
        imageUpload({ file: imageFile, fileName: imageFile.name, filePath: imageFileURL });
        URL.revokeObjectURL(imageFileURL)
      }
```

Function:

```
exports.imageUpload = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const storage = new Storage();
    var filePath = data.filePath;
    var fileName = data.fileName;
    var file = data.file;

    const options = {
        destination: bucket.file('TEST/' + fileName),
        resumable: false
    };

    return new Promise((Resolve, Reject) => {
        async function uploadFile() {
            storage
                .bucket("..............appspot.com")
                .upload(file, options);
            Resolve(fileName);
        }

        uploadFile().catch(error => {
            Reject(error);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the flow something like, first user uploads from browser then the server uploads it to google cloud ?

Comment: No, user only selects files via input field:
<input type="file" id="imageSelected" multiple>
Then it should be uploaded directly upon button click.

Comment: But you are using Cloud Functions as middleman right? You can't directly upload to Google Cloud Storage as that may leak the API keys if you use them on client side .

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: can you share the code where you actually call the Cloud Functions and the that "uploads" the file in your front end?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to upload the file with your Cloud Function as if the cloud function had access to the file in your local filesystem, which it has not being on the server side.

What you need to do is to base64 encode the file as a string, and put that string in the JSON payload, then decode it in the function so that the file can be upload. Note that this is only recommended for small files.

If you need to do this for bigger files a better alternative would to perform the upload in your client, which will then have access to your local filesystem, using the client SDK instead of the admin SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that these files are not smaller than 200-300 kB, so I suppose these are not small enough.
Other thing is that Cloud Storage is not available for node.js:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
So ref.put() doesn't work:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#web-v8_7

Any other idea?

Comment: well, since they are not small enough you can do as I said in the answer, make the client upload directly using the client SDK, which is available in node.js, you can find the documentation for it [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/).